# How to fix 'This page was not found' in Flask Python?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, werkzeug

I'm setting a new server in Flask for an API. And a server to render the frontend in Flask also. Ok, so when i make a request to a determine API route i get this strange response 'This page was not found'. I it really seems to be every thing ok how can i debug this bug? Other Strange thing is that it allways give me status 200 OK. The error is in the route: **@app.route('/v1.0/aluno/update/', methods=['POST'])**

API SIDE

```
@app.route('/v1.0/aluno/<int:aluno_id>', methods=['GET'])
def aluno(aluno_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT NOME, NUMERO, PASSWORD FROM aluno WHERE NUMERO=%s"
        cur.execute(query, (aluno_id,))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        if len(data) <= 0:
            return Response(status=404)
        else:
            aluno = {
                'nome': data[0][0],
                'numero': data[0][1],
                'password': data[0][2]
            }
            js = json.dumps(aluno)
            resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
            resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/aluno'
            return resp

@app.route('/v1.0/aluno/delete/<int:aluno_id>', methods=['POST'])
def aluno_delete(aluno_id):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['_method'] == 'delete':
        query = "DELETE FROM aluno WHERE NUMERO = %s"
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, (aluno_id,))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return Response(status=200)

@app.route('/v1.0/aluno/update/<int:aluno_id>', methods=['POST'])
def aluno_update(aluno_id):
    form = AlunoForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        nome = request.form["nome"]
        numero = request.form["numero"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        query = "UPDATE aluno SET NOME=%s, NUMERO=%s, PASSWORD=%s WHERE NUMERO = %s"
        cur.execute(query, (nome, numero, password, aluno_id))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT NOME, NUMERO FROM aluno WHERE NUMERO = %s", (aluno_id,))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()

        print(" * DATA ")
        print(data)

        aluno = {
            'nome': data[0][0],
            'numero': data[0][1]
        }

        js = json.dumps(aluno)
        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/aluno'
        return resp
    elif request.method == 'POST' and not form.validate():
        resp = Response(status=400)
        resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/aluno'
        return resp
```

FRONT-END SIDE

```
{% endblock %}


<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>

<script>
    function aluno_update(){
        try{
            let formElement = document.getElementById("aluno_update")
            //let formData = formElement.
            //console.log(formData)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:80/v1.0/aluno/update/{{aluno['numero']}}",
                data: {'nome': 'João Luis','numero':'16172','password':'Password'},
                //dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    //location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1.0/alunos/"
                    alert(data)
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error(jqXHR,JQueryXHR,errorThrown){
                    //console.log(formData)
                    alert(jqXHR)
                    alert(JQueryXHR)
                    alert(errorThrown)
                    console.log(jqXHR)
                    console.log(JQueryXHR)
                    console.log(errorThrown)
                }
            })
        }catch(err){
            alert(err)
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have tried using POSTMAN instead of the regular web browser. To make the request to the API. But i get the same response: 'This page was not found'

At least i was expecting some sort of 400 Bad Request or something like that.

https://github.com/joaogracio/SqlParser

Comment: I have no idea where I'm supposed to be looking in all that code for an issue. Do you at least have something for us to go on here?

Comment: @roganjosh yes i am editing im sorry...

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly this line: `url: "http://127.0.0.1:80/v1.0/aluno/update/{{aluno['numero']}}",`: that's not how string interpolation works in javascript and I doubt whatever server side template engine you're using is fixing it either.

Comment: You are mixing 400 - bad request with 404 - page not found. What is the actual HTTP status code that you get? 400 or 404?

Comment: @JaredSmith i supose it is this thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Form validation fails and you get 400 according to the code below

```
   elif request.method == 'POST' and not form.validate():
        resp = Response(status=400)
        resp.headers['Links'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/aluno'
        return resp
```

Comment: The thing is... i never get an 400 i always get an 200 OK with 'This page was not found' @balderman